# Redis: Push multiple items to a List, at a given index

Tags: redis

Does Redis support pushing a list to a list at a given index?

The scenario is simple, pagination. But I don't have any guarantee requests will be performed in a predictable order.

I want to do this:

```
RPUSH("toSomeListKey", list(value1, value2, value3), startIndex))
```

E.g. push the values at a known index. A work around would be using setting an index and appending after that known value, but I'd like to avoid the overhead.

Comment: You can use mass insert https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid a Redis LIST doesn't support this, and/or is a bad fit for your use case.

Both `LINDEX` and `LINSERT` are O(N), so you will probably run into performance issues, even if you bundle the commands in a server-side lua script.

I'd consider implementing it as a `ZSET`.